# How do I implement run time objects (different) implementation with using Python

Tags: python, interface, dependency-injection, plugin-architecture

My requirement is that I have a  standard framework of generating HTML To PDF in 3 steps :

1)Get stuff from our DB and create a meaning out of it , read XML and over-ride or decided settings etc - **pre_processing**

2)Creating an HTML Template using the preprocesed data - **render_template**

3)Run a a HTML to PDF Converted and get the PDF back . - **invoke_service**

Now , its possible that sometimes different PDF engines might be needed and implementations can change ... Its even possible some of them need a very strict data or proprietary settings

So I might need to **extend 1** , **over-ride 2** , **over-ride 3** and I would like to make this implementation configurable and get switchable easily .

I am thinking of creating a Base Class and then creating Foo.py implementation anf Bar.py implementation that are actually going to be the runtime objects . How can I get this with simple Python ?

A terrible way I can think of is:

```
#Module Name ServiceHandler

def implementation(imp_name):
    try:
       from imp_name import imp_class
       return imp_class(AbtractClass) 
    else:
       Sorry No Implemenation Found!

class AbstractClass(...)
      def __init__



Gets invoked in another object method as 


self.ServiceHandler.implementation(read_from_xml)
```

Can anyone give me good pointers to solve this problem ? Basically I want Foo(Base) or Bar(Base) and this should be like read a configuration and map it to that .

My current module layout is :

module.py

- base.py
- foo.py
- bar.py
- unknown.py should be easily extendable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like that :

```
# file : service_handler.py
from importlib import import_module

# get parameters from your config file beforehand
def get_backend(backend_name, **kwargs): 

    # example : foo.Spam gets backend Spam from module foo
    backend_module, backend_class = backend_name.rsplit('.', 1)

    mdl = import_module(backend_module)
    cls = getattr(mdl, backend_class) 

    return cls(**kwargs) # create the object
```

Define your backends as you want to (using abstract classes or duck typing).

This is by no means a complete solution, rather a skeleton pattern that I saw and have done on several projects. You might want to add registry mechanisms, default backends, autodiscover... ymmv.

Projects like django do a lot of multiple-backend stuff, give their codebase a look.

Comment: So you are trying look into framework options and no pure python

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your comment correctly, anyway : The above snippet is pure python without external dependancies. I don't say you *should use* a framework, but that you could *look at how they do things*. Frameworks often have quite robust, fool proof and documented implementations of their features, there's a lot of experience to gain reading their source code.

Comment: Correct . I will look at framework code for inspiration ! You are right many frameworks have done it . The above looks fine too . import_module is interesting . We use Zope and I dont want to use zcml's are complex matters . Tommorow someone wants to migrate this simple thing to another language !